# Vue3 props access inside setup() returns nothing

Tags: vue.js

I have a weird situation with my Vue3 component. I am trying to get a value from the props inside the setup() function. But this returns nothing.

```
<template>
  <div class="border p-2 space-y-2">
    <h2 class="text-center">Makers</h2>
    {{ product.makers }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted, toRef, toRefs } from 'vue'
import ProductStore from '../store/ProductStore'
export default {
  props: {
    product: Object
  },
  setup(props) {
    console.log(props.product.makers)
  },
}
</script>
```

The value is sent from another component like the one below

```
<ProductMakers :product="product"/>
```

But I always get undefined as my response. Any clue to resolve this problem? Am I missing something?

To my surprise, the template is always showing the value correctly. The problem is only inside the setup(). Any clue?

Comment: Not enough info to tell. My guess is you are loading `product` by some async call (fetch) so it is at first undefined/null and later it gets value when loading is finished. Template is "re-rendered" every time some reactive data changes - `setup` is run only once when the component is created

Comment: do you need to pass the product, if your using a store? will ProductMakers be used anywhere else, if so why not pass array of makers an decouple it from products?

Comment: @MichalLevý Yes, the product object was loaded through async call. Now I understood why the product was not available inside setup and available inside template due to re-render behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This means that `product` is reactively updated after the creation of component instance.

Updated value is supposed to be accessed in a watcher or a computed. In case a side effect like logging is needed, this is the case for a watcher:

```
  setup(props) {
    watchEffect(() => {
      if (props.product.makers)
        console.log(props.product.makers)
    });
  },
```

Comment: Added the console statement inside setup is to explain the problem. The actual use-case here is that I need to fetch the full details of the list of makers from the server again. props.product.makers will return here the list of ids of the users. Let me try this watchEffect. Can you share the side effect you mentioned above?

Comment: @Thamizharasu The "side effect" here *is* the call to `console.log(props.product.makers)`.

Comment: @Thamizharasu The effect you really need is to fetch data based on `props.product.makers`, so something like this would work: `watchEffect(() => { if (props.product?.makers?.length) { /* fetch data here */ } })`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I added a v-if condition in the component and the problem got resolved. Thanks for your support.

<ProductMakers v-if="product.makers" :product="product"/>